# Which function returns the recorded audio when I use SpeechRecognizer in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, speech-recognition

I am building a custom keyboard app(in android studio) in which I added a microphone key. I wanted to convert the recorded speech to text so I used speechrecognizer. But I also want the recorded audio. I want that my keyboard app when records the audio in chatting applications like whatsapp, it should send that audio as the message. Could somebody help me how to get the recorded audio when i use speechrecognizer. I need to use speechrecognizer only as i need it for other purpose.
(p.s: my app do not have any activity)
This is the code for recording speech and converting to text.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "com.example.keyboard");

SpeechRecognizer recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this.getApplicationContext());

RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Toast.makeText(EDMTKeyboard.this, "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Toast.makeText(EDMTKeyboard.this, "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        System.err.println("Error listening for speech: " + error);
        Toast.makeText(EDMTKeyboard.this, "ERROR-"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        ArrayList<String> voiceResults = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

        if (voiceResults == null) {
            System.out.println("No voice results");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Printing matches: ");
            for (String match : voiceResults) {
                Toast.makeText(EDMTKeyboard.this, match, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ic.commitText(match,match.length());
                str = str + match;
                I=I+match.length()+1;
                //System.out.println(match);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

    }
};
recognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
recognizer.startListening(intent);
```

I checked the questions similar to this in stackoverflow, but the answers given were not working at present(may be the android studio had removed those functions).